# How to get device details like UUID or name of the device using iBeacons in iOS 7

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Please anybody suggest me to get UUID or device name or any other details of the connected devices through iBeacons.

I'm getting the devices distance, major and minor values using method:

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons              inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region`

But I want know the device details.
Please guide me to reach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Devices don't connect to beacons as it's a high-level, broadcast-only proximity technology.

Beacons advertise their presence and iOS devices can detect these advertisements. You need to know the UUID of the beacons beforehand in order to detect them. The UUIDs are specific to one or more beacons—using more than one beacon with the same UUID allows you to determine the relative proximity of each beacon within range.

The beacons themselves are passive and cannot retrieve the details of nearby iOS devices—at least, not using iBeacon technology.

Comment: ok.I got your answer.But i want to know on which devices are present in my region.Please guide me to get.

Comment: What exactly you do understand by "devices"—do you mean other beacons (with a different proximityUUID) or other iOS devices? Also, what is scanning for these devices—a beacon or an iOS app?

Comment: Sorry for the interruption,I want to find the beacons within the region.

Comment: @laxmi Beacons whose UUID you know or _all_ beacons?

Comment: @Laxmi [You can't programmatically find beacons whose UUIDs you do not know](http://beekn.net/2013/10/ibeacons-can-my-ios-app-find-beacons-that-arent-mine/). The SDK simply does not support this. The UUIDs need to be known ahead of time—either read from a database or plist or hard-coded into the app.

Comment: @neilco, you can't find beacons who's UUIDs you don't know using the beacon API. You CAN using lower-level BLE calls however. I've seen code here in SO that shows how to do it, even.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Proximity UUID using the below method:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    CLBeacon *beacon = [beacons lastObject];
    NSLog(@"Proximity UUID: [%@]", beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString);
}
```

Please check this 
[iBeacons Tutorial for iOS 7 with CLBeaconRegion and CLBeacon](http://www.devfright.com/ibeacons-tutorial-ios-7-clbeaconregion-clbeacon/) for more information.

You can use the `CBPeripheral` delagate for UUID and Services.

```
-(void) peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverServices:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Services scanned !");
    for (CBService *s in peripheral.services)
    {
        NSLog(@"Service found : %@",s.UUID);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had already try this link.But the Proximity UUID is showing [null].

Comment: from that sample app proximity UUID value in empty.

Comment: @Laxmi: I think you are not initializing the Beacon. Check my updated answer

Comment: I had initialised Beacon like                                   CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init]; Even the didDiscoverServices method is not calling.

Comment: @Laxmi: No no, This method won't be called when you initialize the CLBeacon, this method is called when you implement the  CBCentralManager delegate like: `-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    [peripheral discoverServices:nil];
}`

Comment: I had implemented this delegate also.But the method is not calling.

Comment: You still need to know the UUID in advance. You can't connect to a peripheral whose UUID you do not know. That and also the fact that you can't connect to a beacon—you listen for its advertisement.

Comment: @neilco: that information is partially correct: Check http://www.ti.com/ww/en/wireless_connectivity/sensortag/index.shtml?DCMP=lprf-stdroid&HQS=lprf-stdroid-pr and download the code and test it.

Comment: @MidhunMP SensorTag advertises its UUID. Quoting the QuickStart Guide: "_If no Bluetooth 4.0 devices are detected by the SensorTag within 30 seconds, advertising will stop and the SensorTag will go back to sleep. To re-activate advertising and turning on the SensorTag press the side button once more._" An iBeacon is _not_ a peripheral in the sense that is not something you can pair with.